# addToBackStack doesn't work as it supposed to

Tags: android, fragment

```
    public void showErrorFragment(String message, Fragment fragment1) {

    String backStateName = fragment1.getClass().getName();
    Log.d(TAG, "showErrorFragment");
    mFragment = ErrorFragment.newInstance(message);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mFragment, ErrorFragment.TAG)
                .addToBackStack(backStateName)
                .commit();
}
```

When I call  getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate() inside ErrorFragment, 
fragment1 is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using addToBackStack with string arugment you should also use [popBaskStackImmediate](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate(int,%20int)) with string argument

Answer (score 0):

If `fragment1` wasn't in the `R.id.fragmentContainer` before replacing it, then popping the back stack won't show it. That's not how it works.